# Using following-sibling to access divs within following-sibling

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to get information from this URL:

> [https://www.bandsintown.com/e/1024477910-hot-8-brass-band-at-the-howlin'-wolf?came_from=253&utm_medium=web&utm_source=city_page&utm_campaign=event](https://www.bandsintown.com/e/1024477910-hot-8-brass-band-at-the-howlin%27-wolf?came_from=253&utm_medium=web&utm_source=city_page&utm_campaign=event)

I want to extract the text `"Hot 8 Brass Band are a Grammy-nominated New Orleans based brass band, whose sound... "` etc.

My approach: I want to extract the info without using the explicit div name (since that tends to change.) So, I identify the "About Hot 8 Brass Band" using a variable, and then I want to access following-siblings and child divs, etc.

Code:

```
url = "https://www.bandsintown.com/e/1024477910-hot-8-brass-band-at-the-howlin'-wolf?came_from=253&utm_medium=web&utm_source=city_page&utm_campaign=event"

driver.get(url)


#Get artist
try:
    artist = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('a[href^="https://www.bandsintown.com/a/"] h1')
    artist = artist[0].text
    print(artist)
except (ElementNotVisibleException, NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException):
    print ("artist doesn't exist")



#Get Bio Info
try:
    readMoreBio = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[text()='Read More']").click()
    print("Read More Bio Clicked")
except (ElementNotVisibleException, NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException):
    pass



#Once read more clicked, get full bio info
try:
    artistBioDiv = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("(//div[text()='About " + artist + "'])[0]/following-sibling/following-sibling::div")
    print("artistBioDiv is: ", artistBioDiv)

except (ElementNotVisibleException, NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException):
    print ("artist bio doesn't exist")
```

This just seems to access an empty element, i.e. it's not finding the bio paragraph.

Here's the HTML structure:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract the text *...Hot 8 Brass Band are a Grammy-nominated New Orleans based brass band, whose sound... ...* you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *xpath* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.bandsintown.com/e/1024477910-hot-8-brass-band-at-the-howlin'-wolf?came_from=253&utm_medium=web&utm_source=city_page&utm_campaign=event")
  print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='main']//div[text()='About Hot 8 Brass Band']//following-sibling::div[1]//div/div[contains(., 'Hot 8 Brass Band')]").text)
  ```

---

Ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *XPATH* and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.bandsintown.com/e/1024477910-hot-8-brass-band-at-the-howlin'-wolf?came_from=253&utm_medium=web&utm_source=city_page&utm_campaign=event")
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='main']//div[text()='About Hot 8 Brass Band']//following-sibling::div[1]//div/div[contains(., 'Hot 8 Brass Band')]"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Hot 8 Brass Band are a Grammy-nominated New Orleans based brass band, whose sound draws on the traditional jazz heritage of New Orleans, alongside more modern styles incl...
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55241232/7429447)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with the XPATH you used to find the bio.

A few things you could consider for your future projects:

- Use `driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'CSS_SELECTOR_GOES_HERE')` or `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, 'XPATH_GOES_HERE')` since `find_elements_by_xpath` and `find_elements_by_css_selector` are deprecated
- Use `WebDriverWait` to allow enough time for elements to be loaded
- You could also use `normalize-space()` while matching text in xpath as it takes care of leading or trailing spaces

This code should work for you:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException, NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from time import sleep


options = Options()
options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='D://chromedriver/100/chromedriver.exe', options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

url = "https://www.bandsintown.com/e/1024477910-hot-8-brass-band-at-the-howlin'-wolf?came_from=253&utm_medium=web&utm_source=city_page&utm_campaign=event"

driver.get(url)

try:
    # with xpath
    # artist = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//h1[contains(@href, "https://www.bandsintown.com/a")]'))).text
    artist = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'h1[href^="https://www.bandsintown.com/a/"]'))).text
    
    # read more
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[normalize-space()="Read More"]'))).click()
    
    # bio
    bio = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f'//div[normalize-space()="About {artist}"]/following-sibling::div/div[2]/div'))).text
    print(f'Artist: {artist}\nBio:\n{bio}')
except Exception as ex:
    print(f"Error: {ex})
```